# Handling of optional properties of objects to be used as mapped or indexed properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on a scenario of handling an `array` type property with `indexed` access. Tried to encapsulate the problem in simplest form here.

```
type User = {
    readonly name: string; 
    readonly roles: ReadonlyArray<string>;
}

const buildActions = <T extends User>(u: T) => {
    // Implementation
    return {login: (role: T['roles'][number]) => {
        console.log(u, role);
    }}
}

const actions = buildActions({name: 'user', roles: ['admin', 'client']} as const);
actions.login('client');
```

So above code works fine. But in my scenario the property `roles` is optional.

```
type User = {
    readonly name: string; 
    readonly roles?: ReadonlyArray<string>;
}
```

In above case we get error

> Type 'number' cannot be used to index type 'T["roles"]'

I tried to use conditional type to handle the scenario but didn't worked out.

```
const buildActions = <T extends User>(u: T) => {
    // Implementation
    return {login: (role: T['roles'] extends never ? never : T['roles'][number]) => {
        console.log(u, role);
    }}
}
```

Definitely it's not the right way to handle such scenario, but covers the use case very well.

Any idea how to get through this typing scenario?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you'll want `T['roles'] extends string[] ? T['roles'][number] : never`, not test for `never`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried it earlier before posting here. But I think there is some precedence issue with the `extends`, I posted details below. Thanks again for giving the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using the conditional types solved the problem.

```
type User = {
    readonly name: string; 
    readonly roles?: ReadonlyArray<string>;
}

const buildActions = <T extends User>(u: T) => {
    // Implementation
    return {login: (role: T['roles'] extends string[] ? T['roles'][number] : never) => {
        console.log(u, role);
    }}
}

const actions = buildActions({name: 'user', roles: ['admin', 'client']} as const);
actions.login('client');
```

Tried that earlier but seems there is a precedence issues with TS `extends` keyword. Considering that `T['roles']` as type `string[] | undefined` The following code below works fine:

```
T['roles'] extends string[] ? T['roles'][number] : never
```

But if we reverse the condition it fails.

```
T['roles'] extends undefined ? never : T['roles'][number]
```

So never use conditional types with `undefined` assertion.

Comment: Not exactly a precedence issue (with operator parsing), but for `T extends User` the type `T['roles']` is `ReadonlyArray<string> | undefined`, which *does* extend `undefined` (and `string[]` at the same time), so if you reverse the condition you'll get a different result when passing the union type.